# Multiple insert in NodeJS sql server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, sql-insert, bulk

i tried to perform this

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const {database} = require('../keys');  



sql.connect(database, function (err,con) {

        if (err) throw err;
          console.log("Connected!");
          var sql = "INSERT INTO LOGIN (username, clave) VALUES ?";
          var values = [
                    ['John', 'Highway 71'],
                        ['Peter', 'Lowstreet 4'],
                        ['Amy', 'Apple st 652'],
                        ['Hannah', 'Mountain 21'],
                        ['Michael', 'Valley 345'],
                        ['Sandy', 'Ocean blvd 2'],
                        ['Betty', 'Green Grass 1'],
                        ['Richard', 'Sky st 331'],
                        ['Susan', 'One way 98'],
                        ['Vicky', 'Yellow Garden 2'],
                        ['Ben', 'Park Lane 38'],
                        ['William', 'Central st 954'],
                        ['Chuck', 'Main Road 989'],
                        ['Viola', 'Sideway 1633']
                      ];
              con.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);   });
  });
```

however it throws me this error:  `Incorrect syntax near '?'` so isn't possible due sql server restriction.
Is there another way in mssql to perform a multiple insert?